# How to show Browse and Check Names button in Sharepoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-2013

Sharepoint 2010 had a Check Names and Browse button next to the People and Groups (people picker) field.  These buttons don't seem to appear in 2013 by default (at least not in our envirorment).  How can I show these buttons in 2013?

The missing buttons is not much of a problem when you have the field properties set to pick from All Users but it could be a problem when picking from members of a group.    Seems to make sense that someone would want to see the choices in the group.

What is strange is that I have a site that was converted from 2010 to 2013, which has a people picker field and the buttons are appearing.

I did a lot of searching on almost every combination I could think of and could find nothing on this issue.

We are running SharePoint Foundation 2013.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you view the form in SPD of the one that is showing the old control (with the buttons) you should see that it an XSLT view and not the ListFormWebPart.  The ListFormWebPart always displays the new People Picker (without the buttons) but if you create a new form in SPD it will default to the old control in the XSLT view.  You can replace this control with the ClientPeoplePicker control to get the new look / functionality.

Comment: To add to what bondfan posted, all you really need to do is to create a new form for new and edit and this will convert the People Picker fields to the old type.   A bit problematic if you want to have a custom form yet keep the new People Picker look.